# Why aren't the conditions within my while loop working in python?

Tags: python, while-loop, user-defined-functions

I have tried to create a programme where you can play Rock Paper Scissors agains the computer. I managed to make it at a basic level but I wanted to upgrade the game so you can keep track of how many wins the user and computer has in a number of total games the user decides.

I have used a while loop that will execute and continue the game as long as the total games played (excluding ties) doesn't exceed the 'best_of" games the user decides at the beginning. But it isn't working. For example, if I decide I want to play best_of 3 games with computer, and I win 3 times, it will still ask me to input rock paper or scissors.

```
import random

# keep track of who wins throughout the game
user_wins = 0
computer_wins = 0

# list of possible inputs to play the game
options = ["r", "p", "s"]

#user chooses how many games to play on aggregate
best_of = int(input('Best out of: '))

print(best_of)

# define a function that takes in two players as arguments
# and returns True if player wins based on the standard rules
# of rock paper scissors
def is_winner(player, opponent):
    if (player == 'r' and opponent == 's') or \
    (player == 'p' and opponent == 'r') or \
    (player == 's' and opponent == 'p'):
        return True
    
# game continues while the number of games(not inclunding ties) 
# does not exceed best_of
while (user_wins + computer_wins) <= best_of:
    user_input = input("""
    What do you play?
    'r' for rock,
    'p' for paper,
    's' for scissors
    Press 'q' to quit: """).lower()
    
    # loop breaks if user enters 'q'
    if user_input == "q":
        break
    
    # if user_input is not 'r', 'p', or 's', then has to try again
    if user_input not in options:
        continue
    
    #computer selects 'r', 'p' or 's' randomly
    computer_pick = random.choice(options)

    #print each players input
    print("You picked: ", user_input)
    print("Computer picked: ", computer_pick)

    # if inputs are the same then, game is tie and goes through loop again
    if user_input == computer_pick:
        print('It\'s a tie!')
        continue

    # if the player is winner, print a win message and add 1 to the user_wins variable
    elif is_winner(user_input, computer_pick):
        print('You won!')
        user_wins += 1

    # by default, if player doesnt win AND not a tie, the computer wins
    # so prints 'you lost' and add 1 to computer_wins
    else:
        print("You lost!")
        computer_wins += 1

#print final score once game is finshed
print("You won ", user_wins, " times.")
print("The computer won ", computer_wins, " times.")
print("Goodbye!")
```

Comment: This needs debugging. I recommend the following article, though some bits of it (like enabling compiler warnings) are not so relevant to Python: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

```
while (user_wins + computer_wins) <= best_of
```

In above line you checked for <=, So condition will satisfied with 3rd won and allows you to play 4th time.
To stop at 3rd won just use < instead of <=.

```
while (user_wins + computer_wins) < best_of
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this - the issue lies within the while loop:

```
while (user_wins + computer_wins) <= best_of:
```

If the user selects 3, you forgot the fact that both user_wins and computer_wins start at 0 -- thus, it will loop 4 times.

Therefore, the effect you want is simply:

```
while (user_wins + computer_wins) < best_of:
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!  The bug is in the `while` loop condition

Your condition is:
`while (user_wins + computer_wins) <= best_of:`

When the correct is
`while user_wins + computer_wins < best_of:`

1. I removed useless parenthesis (check operator precedence [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence))
2. The condition is `while user_wins + computer_wins < best_of`. When you run `while` loop, it checks condition and then runs code. So, in your case it should break if `user_wins + computer_wins == best_of`. And because of it you should use `<` instead of `<=`

Finally, I reformatted your code with [PEP8](https://pep8.org/). You can do the same thing online [here](http://pep8online.com/).